# Test for invoice_payment.failed event in stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I want to test for the invoice_payment.failed event web hook in stripe. I have set a web hook end point and tried to send test data from stripe but that does not work because the event id is non existent. There are a few solutions mentioned in stripe guidelines. Here is the link I saw.

https://support.stripe.com/questions/test-failed-invoice-payment

It tells me to create a plan and subscribe a customer with the trial_end period set to 1-2 minutes and use a certain credit card number for creating the customer object. I set the trial_end period to "now" and got only the charge.failed using the credit card number given but not the invoice_payment.failed event.  I am new to stripe and would like to know how to set the trial_end period to 1-2 minutes from now and how exactly to test for the invoice_payment.failed event. I am working in php. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When [creating a subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription), you can set the trial period with the [`trial_end`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription-trial_end) parameter.

In order to test the `invoice.payment_failed` event, you can do something like this:

1. First, [create a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) with a card token (from [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js)) created with the special [testing number](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards) `4000 0000 0000 0341`:

   ```
   $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
       "source" => $token,
       "description" => "Test customer"
   ]);
   ```
2. Then, create the subscription to the plan with a short trial period:

   ```
   $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create([
       "customer" => $customer->id,
       "plan" => $plan,
       "trial_end" => strtotime("+1 minute")
   ]);
   ```

This will create the subscription with a one minute trial period. After one minute, an invoice will be created, and approximately one hour later, payment for the invoice will be attempted.

If you don't want to wait one hour, you can manually [retrieve the invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_invoice) after it's been created and [trigger the payment attempt](https://stripe.com/docs/api#pay_invoice):

```
$invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::retrieve($invoice_id);
$invoice->pay();
```

Comment: My plan gets created first and then I try to subscribe a customer to the plan. Will it work if I try to set the trial_end period to strtotime("+2 minutes") while creating the customer? I am yet to try it out.

Comment: I am willing to wait for 1 hour and I am using the api for doing everything

Comment: Yes, you can create the customer and the subscription in a single API call by including the `plan` and `trial_end` parameter in the customer creation request.

Comment: Ywain thanks. I got it working. Both the charge.declined event and the invoice_payment failed event get fired. First time there is a charge decline for $0 and then the invoice gets updated and then again after one hour both charge declined and invoice_payment failed get fired. I wrote my web hook end point. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: I have done as you said, but after I manually hit the inovice pay then it shows card declined, but why my webhook have not worked in this case. Even there is no entry in logs. The toppest entry in logs is about 402 card declined for invoice.I am using  invoice.payment_failed this evint only in my webhook

Comment: Webhook is hitting successfully after run $invoice->pay(); but there is no type name keyword to detect which type of event it is so unable to handle invoice.payment.failed event........any help please

Comment: You can also do `strtotime("+10 seconds")` so you don't have to wait that long haha

Comment: After one hour not invoice.payment_failed event call.

Answer (score 9):

If you just want to test and handle invoice.payment_failed event and others which you can and can't create, then you should go to stripe dashboard and under webhooks settings, send test event of required type.

Answer (score 2):

In new terminal (assuming you have Stripe CLI) just type: stripe trigger invoice.payment_failed

https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/test#forward-events

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use Stripe cards with insufficient funds (E.g `4000000000009995`) , this will trigger `invoice.payment_failed` hook.